# Mediator Pattern Advantage

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, mediator

Im reading the book of GoF. Could you please explain the following Advantage:

It limits subclassing. A mediator localizes behavior that otherwise would
be distributed among several objects. Changing this behavior requires
subclassing Mediator only; Colleague classes can be reused as is.

Is it meant that we should subclass the Mediator or the ConcreteMediator?
Can we have more than one ConcreteMediators that inherit form the same Mediator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book is written in or before 1994, and mainly with examples in C++. Thus, it uses inheritance heavily, partly because C++ allows multiple inheritance, and partly because the language has no separate concept of an *interface* (like Java or C#).

Early in the book, it states as a goal:

> Favor object composition over class inheritance.

Implicit in the book is the understanding that inheritance may not be the best mechanism for reuse.

Consider the example given for the Mediator pattern: the font dialog. Without a Mediator (`FontDialogDirector`) the `ListBox` would need to directly know about the `EntryField` in order to update it about its state change.

A general-purpose `ListBox` should be useful in many contexts, with or without a collaborating `EntryField`. Thus, a reusable `ListBox` class can't know about any 'colleagues', because that would make it non-reusable.

Thus, without a Mediator, you'd need to subclass `ListBox` to connect it to an `EntryField`. In pseudo-C# it might look something like this:

```
public class FontList : ListBox
{
    public FontList(EntryField entryField)
    {
        EntryField = entryField;
    }

    public EntryField EntryField { get; }

    protected override void Changed()
    {
        EntryField.Text = this.Selection;
    }
}
```

This is the very specific kind of subclassing that the Mediator pattern limits.

> Is it meant that we should subclass the Mediator or the ConcreteMediator?

Neither. Notice that the pattern description's *Implementation* subsection states:

> *Omitting the abstract Mediator class.* There's no need to define an abstract Mediator class when colleagues work with only one mediator. The abstract coupling that the Mediator class provides lets colleagues work with different Mediator subclasses and vice versa.

The `Mediator` class acts as a central point of contact for Colleagues. If there's only one Mediator it can be concrete. The distinguishing point is how you propagate change. In the example, each `Widget` propagates change to its `DialogDirector` like this:

```
_director->WidgetChanged(this);
```

We can imagine that `Widget` ought to be a reusable class, so we'd want to decouple it from any concrete Mediator. Here, the assumption is that there might be more than one.

If, on the other hand, you have a specialised set of Colleagues that are *not* reusable, they can communicate via a concrete Mediator. If reuse isn't a requirement in that situation, the Mediator doesn't have to be an abstract class.

Comment: in the implementation part (in the book) could you please explain where should i use the ```void Widget::Changed () {
_director->WidgetChanged(this); }``` part? In the main? (im not good at c++)

Comment: @MichaelMaier I copied that line of code straight out of the book's *Sample Code* section, which explains the context. It's been 20+ years since I did any C++, so I'm not sure, but AFAICT it overrides the `Widget` class' `Changed` method, which I think we should think of as an event handler.